# How to minimize a tkinter app before taking screenshot and then maximize

Tags: python, tkinter, screenshot

I have a python tkinter app script which can take screenshots on pressing the button. But unfortunately while taking the screenshot, the window of the app also gets captured.

Here's the code of the app:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import time


def takeShot():
    sc = ImageGrab.grab()
    path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.png')
    sc.save(path)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root,width=300,height=300)
canvas1.pack()

but = tk.Button(text='Take Screenshot',command=takeShot,bg='green',fg='white',font=10)
canvas1.create_window(150,150,window=but)

root.mainloop()
```

Though it takes the screenshot but app window also gets captured

[image: sample screenshot taken by this app]

I don't want that white window in the screenshot. I tried to minimize the window and then maximise by updating the function like this:

```
def takeShot():
    root.withdraw()
    sc = ImageGrab.grab()
    root.deiconify()
    path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.png')
    sc.save(path)
```

but it didn't work.

**Is there anyway to minimize the app then take the screenshot and then maximize it for save dialogue box so that fulscreen gets captured ??**

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `root.update_idletasks()` after the call to `root.withdraw()` to force tkinter to redraw the window (or in this case, to remove the window from view).

If you find that `root.update_idletasks()` doesn't cause the window to hide on your platform, you can try `root.update()`. `update_idletasks` should work, though.

Comment: I just tried this with `root.update()`, and the window was still present in the screenshot.  I had to add `time.sleep(0.5)` to give Windows' window-closing animation time to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the issue in my Windows running Python 3.8.1.  However, I suggest to move the `asksaveasfilename(...)` right after `root.withdraw()` as `asksaveasfilename(...)` is a modal dialog and returns after it is closed:

```
def take_snapshot():
  root.withdraw()
  filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir='.', defaultextension='.png')
  if filename:
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    image.save(filename)
  root.deiconify()
```